# Replacing Content with CSS - Accessibility Implications?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I want to replace some third party generated content using pure CSS. There are various techniques covered by other questions but the basic idea is hide the exiting content and add new content with pseudo selectors.

I'm interested in whether this is an acceptable thing to do from an accessibility point of view. Would a screen reader see both bits of text or only the original? Should the CSS be wrapped in @media screen {} to avoid both being used?

In my situation I can only use CSS. I can't edit the HTML or use any JavaScript. Is there any way to present only the replacement text to a screen reader?

```css
.third-party-content {
  font-size:0;
}

.third-party-content:before {
  content:"lovely replacement";
  font-size:initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="third-party-content">unwanted garbage</div>
```

Comment: As a side note you cannot also select the new text ... so this is not good for reader and also selection

Comment: css content is for presentation purposes and I think it shouldn't be used as "real content" so I would say that isn't very accessible (but that's my opinion).  You would probably have to do some research into how screen readers and other accessibility devices handle it.  Also it isn't very accessible from a heading and structure point of view so accessibility users won't be able to tab through the headings like normal content

Comment: In my particular use case it's some guidance text on a form so selection or tabbing are not particularly important but good to know.

Comment: Can't you use JavaScript instead to replace the text?

Comment: No, as stated above. Unfortunately for me the third party strips out any JavaScript content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `font-size` to 0 just changes the visual appearance of the text but does not hide it from a screen reader.  A screen reader does not care what size the font is.  It's just text that will be read.

When a screen reader reads text, it's called the "accessible name".  The accessible name is computed according to these rules - https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2.  In particular, see step 2.F.ii

> "ii. Check for CSS generated textual content associated with the current node and include it in the accumulated text.  The CSS `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements can provide textual content for elements that have a content model."

One way to hide text from a screen reader is to use the `aria-hidden` attribute but that would require changing the HTML, which you stated you can't do.  Text is also hidden using standard `display:none`, but that would obviously hide your `:before` text too.

Using CSS tricks to visually hide text, such as `clip`, `position`, `width`, etc, again just visually hides the text but does not hide it from a screen reader.

I'm not a CSS expert but building on your attempted solution of `font-size`, I added `visibility:hidden` and it seemed to work.  I know `hidden` just makes the text invisible but still takes up space on the screen, but when combined with your `font-size:0` (and `inherit`) it prevents the "unwanted garbage" from taking up any space so if you had an element adjacent to your original, you wouldn't have a big gap between the two.

`visibility:hidden` **does** hide the element from the screen reader.

```
.third-party-content {
  font-size:0;
  visibility:hidden;
}

.third-party-content:before {
  content:"lovely replacement";
  font-size:initial;
  visibility:initial;
}
```

You cannot use `display:none` in a similar solution because as soon as the parent is hidden, the `:before` is hidden too.

**Update**: This solution works with NVDA (screen reader) on firefox and VoiceOver on iOS.  (Chrome with screen readers is typically not tested because Chrome has sporadic support for screen readers.)  It does **not** work with JAWS on Internet Explorer but IE seems to have two problems.  The first is that your `font-size:initial` does not work on the `:before`.  I had to set it to `font-size:16px`.  Second is that IE does not correctly compute the text to be read as noted in step 2.F.ii above.  IE is not honoring the `content` property so "unwanted garbage" is still read (and "lovely replacement" is **not** read).  Since step 2.F.ii is a W3 spec, I'd say IE has a bug.

If `content` were correctly read by IE, then there **might** still be a problem.  Since `font-size:inherit` doesn't work in IE, `visibility:inherit` **might** not work either.  (I tried a simple case and it didn't work.  Setting `visibility:visible` on `:before` also didn't work on IE.)

Comment: Thank you for a fantastic answer. That's all I could have wanted and more. I do need to support IE11 so it doesn't look like a viable solution. In my case the "unwanted garbage" is probably preferable to unpredictable or inconsistent content and I'm not prepared to serve something which will work for screen users only.

Comment: IE11 has other problems, as noted, so no matter what you do, it might not be ideal. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: A few years late on this reply, but wouldn't OP be able to wrap the injected code in HTML marked with 'aria-hidden', since that attribute is inherited downwards? I feel like that's the cleanest a11y solution.

Comment: @KaneFord, the OP said they couldn't change the HTML, only the CSS.  `aria-hidden` is an HTML attribute.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use CSS generated text to convey meaningful information at all.

Screen readers don't behave the same. Some of them always read it, some of them never, and some of them sometimes do or don't depending on other properties.
For example, NVDA reads CSS generated text most of the time; Jaws rarely does (if ever it does sometimes).

Anyway, according to the base separation principle: content/structure=HTML, behavior/action=JavaScript, appearance=CSS, it isn't semantically correct to let CSS generate meaningful text.
It should be done in HTML. In fact the CSS `Content` propertiy should never be used for something else than text icons and other pure visual things that don't really matter for general understanding if they are skipped / not shown / not read.

Comment: Thank you. I completely agree but if it could be achieved with no detrimental effects I have to admit I would be tempted to cross that line.

Comment: Reinforcing this point: the content has to be understandable independently of the CSS, that is, considering only the HTML. Think that the content has to be available to the users even if you remove all the CSS from the page.